# Slow loading site 1.8 - next steps?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have been through all of the standard things for speeding up magento 1.8:

Compressed and combined stylesheets and javascripts.
 Enabled magento compiler.
emptied log tables in db.
Disabled logging.

Installed APC as an opcode cache using recommended settings
 Enabled caching and compression in apache.

Am using Argento theme.

What else can I do?

Was looking at varnish and redis but not sure if these are appropariate for a site with small catalogue and seems like there must be other simpler things I can do.

How can I debug where the problem is, page speed insights says slow server response and I get only 52 on the page speed insights score.

Any help on how to debug this gratefully received.

Paul

UPDATE:
Testing page speed insights over time it seems there is a high variability over weeks as to what score is achieved. I'm wondering if that means it is down to the server rather than magento site alone. Anyone?

Comment: Might some code is the issue. Might be the number of categories in menu, products etc. Doing above things will make normal magento to load faster.

Comment: you mean only slow server response time??? so you have to run Aoe_Profiler

Comment: I have tried installing AOE_Profiler and can't get it to appear in the footer. Have done all the usual stuff, installed with composer, enabled in local.xml backend AND index.php still doesn't appear. clleared cache. Restarted apache to flush apc cache. Bit stumped tbh.

Comment: Have resolved AOEProfiler issue by installing with modman but have no idea of what it is showing me. Can you guys see any issues in this profiler output shot?[https://www.dropbox.com/s/rnr5sl03g233h37/Screenshot%202015-05-19%2009.15.03.png?dl=0] Seems like 5s to load index.php is a lot. Any suggestions of how I can understand what should be expected as good performance and what bad in thsi profiler?

Comment: Which page are you troubling with? Product page or catalog page? Or entire site?

Comment: have been testing home page.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues that can cause a slow site:

1. Time to first byte values
2. Page size in MB
3. Server Configuration

I would suggest first following the steps listed by Guido jansen in the following blog post

http://www.gxjansen.com/101-ways-to-speed-up-your-magento-e-commerce-website/

In my experience the pre-made templates rely heavily on the configuration (most of the time thats the case) enabling the config cache usually speed up the store.